# How to make wrap content push button for show label on Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

Label on the push button is "Choose Something That Has a Long Name". But as you can see it does not fit. I want to make it wrap content somehow. (
can be in 2 rows) How can I do it?

Button

[image: Button]

Property Palette

[image: Property Palette]

Property Palette...

[image: Property Palette...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `PRE-FORM` trigger and put something like this in there:

```
set_item_property('btn_so',label,'This is a very long label'||chr(10)||'which does not fit');
```

As you can resize the button (simply by dragging its *resize handler* on the canvas, you can adjust button's width & height so that that very long label fits.

Comment: You should do this in a pre-form trigger, not a pre-block. Otherwise it will fire to much

Comment: Makes sense; I modified the answer. Thank you, @nightfox79.

Comment: I couldn't find Pre-form trigger in my form (Forms Version is 10.1.2.3.0 ), I do this in pre-block and worked at least. Also I can not resize the button by dragging. So, thank you all.

Comment: You'd *add* that trigger: right-click "Triggers" in Object Navigator, go to "Smart triggers", go to "Other" and find PRE-FORM. Button can be resized either by using the mouse, or by opening its property palette and setting "Width" and "Height" under its Physical properties.

Comment: "Pre-Form" is okey, thanks for describing (I'm new on Oracle Forms). I can resize but I can not show it in 2 rows so it doesn't work for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting it dynamically with a `CHR(10)` or `CHR(13)` in between